# Evaluate a list of Expressions from file

Tags: equation-solving, export, text

I have a list of expressions in a text file. I would like mathematica to evaluate and export the results at the end of the same file or in a new file. The expressions are in seperate lines in the text file.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat a.txt
{Series[f[x],{x,x0,10}],Plot[Sin[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}]}
```

Then

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
expr = Import["a.txt"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
result = ToExpression[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["result.txt", result]
```

then

```
>cat result.txt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]